# Как посмотреть документацию класса из visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Сейчас вбиваю название класса c# в поисковик и смотрю на сайте msdn, но наверняка есть более удобный способ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установить курсор в имя класа и нажать <kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: оу.............

Comment: И вдогонку, сейчас по ф1 открывается английская справка, как сделать, чтобы открывалась русская?

Comment: @Alex если у вас интерфейс студии английский, то так и должно быть. А вообще читайте лучше английский вариант если можете, машинный перевод ужасен, иногда до искажения смысла.